# MacBook Pro 2020 running Catalina 10.15.6 does not sleep at night

Tags: macos, battery, sleep-wake

I've had this issue for about a month. I've done the factory reset and my Mac was fine for a week but is now slowly going back to draining the battery overnight. I've tried everything to fix it and I'm not sure where to go from here. I'm sure if I go to Apple they will tell me it's some sort of bug.

Before I did the factory reset it would run literally all night doing the same set of actions over and over, resulting in a large battery drain - here are the results from that ([(help) 2020 MacPro battery draining overnight](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/ia31l3/help_2020_macpro_battery_draining_overnight/)).

Some additional information:

1. My Bluetooth is always off
2. I close all apps at night
3. I've gone to Activity Monitor to find out what is preventing sleep but it's just the OS systems, none of the (very few) apps I have installed.

I'm not too flash with computers so I will just post the terminal log results that my Mac repeats all throughout the night. Please help!

```
2020-08-23 02:43:15.897514+1000  localhost bluetoothd[141]: (IOBluetooth) [com.apple.bluetooth:CBPower] PMConnectionHandler - Dark Wake IOPMSystemPowerStateCapabilities - Sleep
2020-08-23 02:43:15.979505+1000  localhost rapportd[355]: (CoreUtils) [com.apple.CoreUtils:CUSleepWakeMonitor] CLink: State changed: Sleep -> DarkWake, 0x1 < DarkWake >
2020-08-23 02:43:16.170955+1000  localhost bluetoothd[141]: (SPOwner) [com.apple.icloud.SPOwner:powerManagement] Wake time calculated as - [Sun Aug 23 03:43:16 2020]
2020-08-23 02:43:16.235219+1000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleIntelCFLGraphicsFramebuffer) [IGFB][INFO   ] FB0 power state transition Sleep to Doze
2020-08-23 02:43:16.278061+1000  localhost powerd[100]: [powerd:sleepWake] Wake reason: "<private>"  identity: "<private>"
2020-08-23 02:43:16.365119+1000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleIntelCFLGraphicsFramebuffer) [IGFB][INFO   ] FB1 power state transition Sleep to Doze
2020-08-23 02:43:16.374692+1000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleIntelCFLGraphicsFramebuffer) [IGFB][INFO   ] FB2 power state transition Sleep to Doze
2020-08-23 02:43:16.506467+1000  localhost bluetoothd[141]: (IOBluetooth) [com.apple.bluetooth:CBPower] PMConnectionHandler - Dark Wake IOPMSystemPowerStateCapabilities - Sleep
2020-08-23 02:43:16.508787+1000  localhost bluetoothd[141]: (SPOwner) [com.apple.icloud.SPOwner:powerManagement] Wake time calculated as - [Sun Aug 23 05:43:16 2020]
2020-08-23 02:43:16.524214+1000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2020-08-23 02:43:23.622093+1000  localhost powerd[100]: [powerd:sleepWake] Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep'
2020-08-23 02:43:23.623762+1000  localhost rapportd[355]: (CoreUtils) [com.apple.CoreUtils:CUSleepWakeMonitor] CLink: State changed: DarkWake -> Sleep, 0x20 < Sleep >
2020-08-23 02:43:23.623770+1000  localhost rapportd[355]: (CoreUtils) [com.apple.CoreUtils:CUSleepWakeMonitor] CLink: Sleep async ack
2020-08-23 02:43:23.624121+1000  localhost bluetoothd[141]: (SPOwner) [com.apple.icloud.SPOwner:powerManagement] Network off sleep date is not setup yet. Wake date cannot be calculated without baseline.
2020-08-23 02:43:32.680487+1000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.RTC (Alarm)
2020-08-23 02:43:32.680489+1000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.RTC (Alarm)
2020-08-23 03:23:01.457052+1000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleIntelCFLGraphicsFramebuffer) [IGFB][INFO   ] FB0 power state transition Sleep to Wake
2020-08-23 03:23:01.476498+1000  localhost rapportd[355]: (CoreUtils) [com.apple.CoreUtils:CUSleepWakeMonitor] CLink: State changed: Sleep -> FullWake, 0x10 < UserWake >
2020-08-23 03:23:01.476996+1000  localhost bluetoothd[141]: (IOBluetooth) [com.apple.bluetooth:CBPower] PMConnectionHandler - Full Wake IOPMSystemPowerStateCapabilities - Sleep
2020-08-23 03:23:01.477002+1000  localhost corespeechd[501]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemonMac _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>
2020-08-23 03:23:01.477033+1000  localhost corespeechd[501]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemonMac _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3
2020-08-23 03:23:01.482256+1000  localhost contextstored[179]: (KnowledgeMonitor) [com.apple.coreduet.context:] Idle Sleep Preventers Count: 1
2020-08-23 03:23:01.483212+1000  localhost contextstored[179]: (KnowledgeMonitor) [com.apple.coreduet.context:] Idle Sleep Preventers: <private>
2020-08-23 03:23:01.485190+1000  localhost contextstored[179]: (KnowledgeMonitor) [com.apple.coreduet.context:] Idle Sleep Preventers Count: 1
2020-08-23 03:23:01.485531+1000  localhost contextstored[179]: (KnowledgeMonitor) [com.apple.coreduet.context:] Idle Sleep Preventers: <private>
2020-08-23 03:23:01.490867+1000  localhost contextstored[179]: (KnowledgeMonitor) [com.apple.coreduet.context:] Idle Sleep Preventers Count: 1
2020-08-23 03:23:01.491113+1000  localhost contextstored[179]: (KnowledgeMonitor) [com.apple.coreduet.context:] Idle Sleep Preventers: <private>
2020-08-23 03:23:01.496943+1000  localhost contextstored[179]: (KnowledgeMonitor) [com.apple.coreduet.context:] Idle Sleep Preventers Count: 1
2020-08-23 03:23:01.497094+1000  localhost contextstored[179]: (KnowledgeMonitor) [com.apple.coreduet.context:] Idle Sleep Preventers: <private>
2020-08-23 03:23:01.499565+1000  localhost contextstored[179]: (KnowledgeMonitor) [com.apple.coreduet.context:] Idle Sleep Preventers Count: 1
2020-08-23 03:23:01.499678+1000  localhost contextstored[179]: (KnowledgeMonitor) [com.apple.coreduet.context:] Idle Sleep Preventers: <private>
2020-08-23 03:23:01.500511+1000  localhost contextstored[179]: (KnowledgeMonitor) [com.apple.coreduet.context:] Idle Sleep Preventers Count: 1
2020-08-23 03:23:01.500566+1000  localhost contextstored[179]: (KnowledgeMonitor) [com.apple.coreduet.context:] Idle Sleep Preventers: <private>
2020-08-23 03:23:01.504674+1000  localhost contextstored[179]: (KnowledgeMonitor) [com.apple.coreduet.context:] Idle Sleep Preventers Count: 1
2020-08-23 03:23:01.504763+1000  localhost contextstored[179]: (KnowledgeMonitor) [com.apple.coreduet.context:] Idle Sleep Preventers: <private>
2020-08-23 03:23:01.508445+1000  localhost contextstored[179]: (KnowledgeMonitor) [com.apple.coreduet.context:] Idle Sleep Preventers Count: 1
2020-08-23 03:23:01.508662+1000  localhost contextstored[179]: (KnowledgeMonitor) [com.apple.coreduet.context:] Idle Sleep Preventers: <private>
2020-08-23 03:23:01.509808+1000  localhost contextstored[179]: (KnowledgeMonitor) [com.apple.coreduet.context:] Idle Sleep Preventers Count: 1
2020-08-23 03:23:01.509889+1000  localhost contextstored[179]: (KnowledgeMonitor) [com.apple.coreduet.context:] Idle Sleep Preventers: <private>
2020-08-23 03:23:01.767438+1000  localhost contextstored[179]: (KnowledgeMonitor) [com.apple.coreduet.context:] Idle Sleep Preventers Count: 1
2020-08-23 03:23:01.767559+1000  localhost contextstored[179]: (KnowledgeMonitor) [com.apple.coreduet.context:] Idle Sleep Preventers: <private>
2020-08-23 03:23:01.818072+1000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleIntelCFLGraphicsFramebuffer) [IGFB][INFO   ] FB1 power state transition Sleep to Wake
2020-08-23 03:23:01.830721+1000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleIntelCFLGraphicsFramebuffer) [IGFB][INFO   ] FB2 power state transition Sleep to Wake
2020-08-23 03:23:01.987903+1000  localhost powerd[100]: [powerd:sleepWake] Wake from Standby [CDNVA] : due to EC.RTC/Alarm
2020-08-23 03:23:01.989572+1000  localhost bluetoothd[141]: (IOBluetooth) [com.apple.bluetooth:CBPower] PMConnectionHandler - Full Wake IOPMSystemPowerStateCapabilities - Sleep
2020-08-23 03:23:01.993118+1000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2020-08-23 03:23:02.024059+1000  localhost powerd[100]: [powerd:assertions] Process (null).0 Released Idle Sleep Preventer "IODisplayWrangler" age: id:0 [System: PrevIdle IPushSrvc kCPU]
2020-08-23 03:23:02.032765+1000  localhost VDCAssistant[279]: [com.apple.VDCAssistant:device] [guid:0x8020000005ac8514] Sleep -> ClamshellClosed on event kSystemWake
2020-08-23 03:23:02.036662+1000  localhost bluetoothd[141]: (SPOwner) [com.apple.icloud.SPOwner:powerManagement] Wake time calculated as - [Sun Aug 23 05:43:16 2020]
2020-08-23 03:23:02.037793+1000  localhost bluetoothd[141]: (IOBluetooth) [com.apple.bluetooth:CBPower] PMConnectionHandler - Dark Wake IOPMSystemPowerStateCapabilities - Sleep
2020-08-23 03:23:02.046635+1000  localhost VDCAssistant[279]: [com.apple.VDCAssistant:device] [guid:0x8020000005ac8514] ClamshellClosed -> Sleep on event kSystemSleep
2020-08-23 03:23:03.829948+1000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleIntelCFLGraphicsFramebuffer) [IGFB][INFO   ] FB0 power state transition Wake to Doze
2020-08-23 03:23:32.038164+1000  localhost powerd[100]: [powerd:sleepWake] Entering Sleep state due to 'Clamshell Sleep'
2020-08-23 03:23:32.039044+1000  localhost rapportd[355]: (CoreUtils) [com.apple.CoreUtils:CUSleepWakeMonitor] CLink: State changed: DarkWake -> Sleep, 0x20 < Sleep >
2020-08-23 03:23:32.039107+1000  localhost rapportd[355]: (CoreUtils) [com.apple.CoreUtils:CUSleepWakeMonitor] CLink: Sleep async ack
2020-08-23 03:23:32.039709+1000  localhost bluetoothd[141]: (SPOwner) [com.apple.icloud.SPOwner:powerManagement] Network off sleep date is not setup yet. Wake date cannot be calculated without baseline.
2020-08-23 03:23:38.366300+1000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleIntelCFLGraphicsFramebuffer) [IGFB][INFO   ] FB1 power state transition Wake to Sleep
2020-08-23 03:23:38.372576+1000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleIntelCFLGraphicsFramebuffer) [IGFB][INFO   ] FB2 power state transition Wake to Sleep
2020-08-23 03:23:39.640803+1000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.RTC (Alarm)
2020-08-23 03:23:39.640806+1000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.RTC (Alarm)
2020-08-23 04:17:06.185198+1000  localhost corespeechd[501]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemonMac _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>
2020-08-23 04:17:06.185206+1000  localhost corespeechd[501]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemonMac _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3
```

Comment: Take a look at this [Apple Support Page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204760) and see if this helps any.

Answer (score 0):

Buried in the log is

```
Wake reason: EC.RTC (Alarm)
```

This is the real time clock and can be triggered by an alarm on the Mac.  I would check if you have anything set to wake the Mac up - backups with TimeMachine, other programs that check things like messages / mail even power saving / sleep options.

It could be worth resetting the PRAM/NVRAM and SMC to clear any corrupt settings.

You could try booting into safe mode and see if it still behaves that way.

Try setting the disks to sleep when possible

Check if Bluetooth devices can wake the computer - if possible try this as NO (maybe an issue if you have a BT keyboard and mouse - not that I ever did that - no not me !)

Are you sharing disks / printers / music?  Try turning them off.

Sorry it's a bit long - **try the SMC reset first**.

Comment: thank you! unfortunately, this has not worked for me! i contacted apple and they were truly stunned with my issue so i'm gonna have to take it in :(

Answer (score 0):

To manually initiate a sleep on the mac and override 'Preventing Sleep' applications run

`pmset sleepnow`

in the terminal

(you may find something in `man pmset` that can alter the settings, I performed a quick look but couldn't find anything)